# Open .swf file in web view android

Tags: android, flash, video, webview

I am trying to open .swf file into web view from assets folder.But the .swf file doesn't open.It just display black screen not a video which I want.The code I have tried till now is given below:

```
mSWFPlayer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_swfPlayer);
mSWFPlayer.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mSWFPlayer.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mSWFPlayer.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/lovebirds.swf");
```

There is also an Internet Permission and android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in Manifest file.
And I have also install adobe flash from this site...[this](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives)
And my logcat shows the message like this:

```
  5-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1683)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7900(WebViewCore.java:926)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1795)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2917)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:593)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:984)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me if you have any idea.I have almost visit all the sites related this problem but I didn't get any solution.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to do something with component, which is not initialized yet. Wait for WebView's initialization and then launch your SWF.

I mean this error line:

```
5-09 13:33:30.187: W/webcore(20054): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
```

Some large objects (such as WebView) take a few time to initialize. It means, this component won't be ready the very moment you created it.

Comment: Sorry I can't get what you have said..@JustLogin